# Informix memory leak

Tags: c#, sql, .net, memory-leaks, informix

I am running into an strange issue using Informix (specifically, I am using the IBM.Data.Informix namespace, 4.10 Client SDK).  I am connecting to an IBM Informix database using ODBC and am running into memory leak issues.  The documentation is fairly sparse, and I am locked into using the driver/SDK I currently have installed.  Here is the code I am using for the database context:

```
public class IfxDbContext : IIfxDbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    //private readonly IfxConnection _connection;

    public IfxDbContext(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        //IfxConnection conn = new IfxConnection(connectionString) {ConnectionString = connectionString};

        //_connection = conn;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
    {
        var items = new List<Item>();

        try
        {
            using (IfxConnection conn = new IfxConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (IfxCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "VALID SQL COMMAND";

                    IfxDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        //add to items
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IfxException ex)
        {

        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

}

I have tried disposing and closing any connection I can, but that doesn't seem to help.  Am I missing something or is it an issue with the driver?  The question then becomes, what can I do to free up memory incrementally?  The app hits around ~1200 MB and crashes.

My particular errors are "Not enough space for parser stacks" and "Memory allocation failure".

Am I missing something?

Comment: When you wrote that you are disposing and closing any connection, are you also disposing/closing all the other objects: IfxCommand, IfxDataReader, etc ?

Comment: @LuísMarques yes, I closed and disposed everything I could.  Looking into it more, it might be a Castle Windsor issue.  That's my current line of thought and I'm investigating it currently.

Comment: Get memory profiler and see what objects are not freed and why, don't guess

Comment: I have the same issue with the same version of the SDK. This has been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that this is an issue with the specific version of the SDK I am using for the project (4.10 - 32 bit).  Unless you leave both the connection and the command open indefinitely, the application will leak memory.  This isn't really a solution because there is a finite number of connections and that quickly runs out if I have multiple connections to the application.  Because I need to continue using this specific SDK version, I configured IIS to recycle the app pool when it reached a memory threshold (1 GB in my instance).  That resolved the issue for now, although it does nothing to address the underlying issue with the SDK.

Comment: I can't tell you how crazy this has been driving me for the past few days. Did you find any other solutions as I can't leave connections open. I have Ajax queries hitting every 10 seconds. I however am not locked into using the SDK if I can connect another way,

Comment: @Tsukasa I wasn't able to find any other solution for this issue or any alternative way to connect to the database.  Are you not able to recycle the IIS app pool every so often?  So far that solution has worked well for me with no interruption of service.  I hit the endpoint once every few seconds without trouble.

Comment: I have rewritten my classes as well as made one using ODBC. I'll be testing both and see what happens with ram. I don't have the ram snapshots in front of me but if I remember correctly it had something to do with CNativeBuffer. Now I'm not to sure what is going on in side but I see lots of Marshaling as well as GC.KeepAlive calls in the Dispose.