# High Memory Usage While Running Stored Proc (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, memory, memory-management, informix

I seem to have some sort of memory/RAM issue on an ASP.NET 3.5 website I am working on. Currently we are running a 2 server web farm with Windows 2012, both on virtual servers. When more users log on and start using the application, especially running intensive database work, the memory usage on that w3wp.exe process will shoot up very high (up to 2.5-3 GB).

I've tried a number of things already to help solve this issue:

- Request for increase of RAM on the virtual servers
- Ensure all database connections and readers are in "using" statements
- Adjusted any parts in the code where datasets where being saved into Session variables, various other Session variable cleanups
- Tried analyzing memory dumps using WinDbg and the like, with no real significant issue that jumped out at me on the logs

What I have noticed however, is that the memory seems to shoot up really high when intensive database work is being done. I have a button on the website that when clicked, all it does is call a stored procedure (FYI - this is an Informix, not SQL database).

From the ASP.NET page -

```
Dim SWS As New PurchaseOrders

Protected Sub btnFunction_Click (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFunction.Click

        SWS.MyFunctionCall()

End Sub
```

In an App_Code file's method call -

```
Using Conn As New IfxConnection(ConnectToInformix())
            Conn.Open()

            Dim cmd As New IBM.Data.Informix.IfxCommand()
            cmd.Connection = Conn
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
            cmd.CommandText = "auto_order"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@storeID", IfxType.Integer)

            cmd.Parameters("@storeID").Value = store_id

            Dim value As String
            value = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

            If (value = "1") Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
    End Using
```

The stored procedure runs fine, but users will continuously run this in succession. Meanwhile there are other database functions being run by other users anyway. So when this is happening, the memory jumps high to 2.5-3 GB. I have resorted to adding memory limit thresholds in IIS because if it gets past about 3.5 GB memory usage everything on the website will return Object Reference errors. So once it reaches memory limit, it will recycle and of course log users out.

Anyone got any ideas? Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a memory leak issue possibly in the informix driver. Can you try profiling with some memory profiler? You can use some good memory profiler fewdays free in trials.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Do you think this information would apply? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597695/informix-memory-leak